# SQL Math Order of Operations

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why doesn't this produce 50 when I use this select statement in SSMS? Instead, it returns '0'.

`select ((1500-1000)/1000)*100`

Comment: Integer division?

Comment: Simple rounding...

Answer (score 1):

Because SQL Server does integer division.  So `1500 - 1000` is `500`.  And `500 / 1000` is `0`, not `0.5`.

You can introduce a decimal point for more precision:

```
((1500-1000)/1000.0)*100
```